# Felix Scr change log levels

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, apache-servicemix

I am using Apache ServiceMix 7.0.1 with Felix SCR. On startup, a number of my OSGI components are in Disabled / Unsatisfied state. In order to get some additional logs around the lifecycle of the components, I looked at changing the log levels for scr and found this article - 
http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-service-component-runtime.html
But I am not clear on where to set the ds.loglevel property in ServiceMix. I tried setting the same in config.properties and also by passing as a launch argument via -D option but it did not result in any additional logging.

Can you please advise me on how to troubleshoot the failing components?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know scr is using the OSGi log service. In many log configurations these logs are not forwarded to the log backend.

I recently found that felix now offers a new logging solution based on logback that also works for log service as well as several types of OSGi events. So I propose you try with felix logback support bundle.

Here is a blog how to set it up:
http://liquid-reality.de/2018/08/07/logging-osgi.html

Edit: The blog text is below, slightly worse formatted, from a time when the link appeared to be dead because it had moved from blog.liquid-reality.de.

> Logging in OSGi seemed to be an arcane thing for quite some time. On
>   the logback website there is still [this explanation by Ekke](http://ekkes-corner.blogspot.com/2008/10/index-blogseries-logging-in-osgi.html) which was
>   surely good 2008 but in 2018 people do not accept creating their own
>   logging bridges, adding config using fragments and tweaking start
>   levels.
>
> Luckily this all improved quite a lot. Apache Karaf uses pax-logging
>   and there is now also the [felix logback support bundle](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-logback.html). In this
>   article I will focus on the latter as it is simple to setup and has
>   some nice features.
>
> ## Example code
>
> I added the felix logback support to my [OSGi DS hello
>   world example](https://github.com/cschneider/osgi-ds-hello-world) because logging is a core aspect in any professional
>   development.
>
> See the Readme in the example for instruction how to build and run it.
>
> ## Logging frontends
>
> Logback + Felix logback supports a wide range of
>   logging frontends (slf4j, jul, log4j, logback, commons logging, OSGi
>   Log service). For your own code I recommend to use the slf4j API. It
>   is very slim in dependencies and provides a lot of features.
>
> At compile time you only need the slf4j API.
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>  
>    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
>    <version>1.7.25</version>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> You instantiate slf4j exactly like outside OSGi. So it
>   can also be used for hybrid code that can run inside and outside of
>   OSGi.
>
> ```
> class MyClass {
>     Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass()); }
> ```
>
> ## Deployment
>
> At runtime you install the bundles below. These also
>   include the Felix log service which is used by some OSGi reference
>   implementations.
>
> ```
> <dependency>   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>  
> <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>   <version>1.7.25</version>
> </dependency> <dependency>
>     <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
>     <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
>     <version>1.2.0</version> </dependency> <dependency>
>     <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
>     <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
>     <version>1.2.0</version> </dependency> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
>     <artifactId>org.apache.felix.log</artifactId>
>     <version>1.2.0</version> </dependency> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
>     <artifactId>org.apache.felix.logback</artifactId>
>     <version>1.0.0</version> </dependency>
> ```
>
> The simplest way to install these is to use the bndtools bndrun packaging like in the example
>   above.
>
> ## Configuration
>
> The logback configuration can be provided by a framework
>   property. Logback will automatically watch the file for changes and
>   apply new settings.
>
> ```
> -runproperties: logback.configurationFile=file:${.}/logback.xml
> ```
>
> You can use plain logback configs but felix logback also provides some
>   special settings to configure OSGi specific logs like bundle events.
>   See the [examples in the felix logback docs](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-logback.html).
>
> An example config can be found [here](https://github.com/cschneider/osgi-ds-hello-world/blob/master/starter/logback.xml).